# Saving data frame to sqlite table with constraint

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlite

I am having a trouble saving a data frame to sqlite database.

I have a sqlite database with table `assignments` where I have `employee_id` and `project_id` as composite key.

I want to store data frame where I can possibly have rows that I already have in a table (same `employee_id` and `project_id`). While saving that data frame, if there are rows that are in table, it throws me the following error:
`UNIQUE constraint failed: assignments.employee_id , assignments.project_id`.
I don't want my operation to be interrupted, but to discard those duplicate rows and save other rows.

I tried with `if_exists='append'`, but it gave me an error mentioned earlier:

Following is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///my_database.db')
data = {
    'employee_id': [1, 2],
    'project_id': ['ABC123', 'DEF456']
}
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_new.to_sql('assignments', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Comment: Query the db for existing ids, then filter your df to remove them before saving.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [official doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html), the `if_exists` parameter is related to tables, not rows (This determines behavior when the table already exists).

One solution would be to remove records that already exist in the table from the data frame. like this:

```
# read data from table
table_assignments_df = pd.read_sql(
    'SELECT employee_id, project_id FROM assignments', conn
)

# exclude existing rows from the new data frame 
df_new = df_new.loc[
    ~df_new['employee_id'].isin(table_assignments_df['employee_id'])
    & ~df_new['project_id'].isin(table_assignments_df['project_id'])
]

# then, store new data to table
df_new.to_sql('assignments', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```